# Ajax loading not stop if data is empty

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

i am using ajax request to get the data, and also i use loading to start and stop ajax. if the data is not empty the loading work perfeclty, but if the data is empty, the ajax cannot stop the loading. i use ajaxStart and ajaxStop to do it.

this is my js code:

```
<script>
$(function() {
$("#searchgrowh").click(function() {
    $('#result').html("");

    $('.loading').ajaxStart(function(){$(this).show();});//this method for ajax start
    $('.loading').ajaxStop(function(){$(this).hide();});//this method for ajax stop
    $('.loading').ajaxError(function(){$(this).hide();});

     $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo base_url();?>internal/trending/ajaxsubmit/",
        data:  $('#form').serialize(),
        success: function(html){
            $("#result").prepend(html);
        },

    });
    return false;
});

});
</script>
```

Comment: I believe you may need to add a function to check if the data is empty

Comment: @MrTechie, thanks. such as this code ?
if(data != 'null'){
   $("#result").prepend(html);
}

Answer (score 1):

please see
[.ajaxStart and .ajaxStop not firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6604991/ajaxstart-and-ajaxstop-not-firing)

also i've had luck with

ajaxSuccess
and
ajaxComplete

Comment: the problem of the link that you have put is parenthesis, i have put it and not work. i also try to use  ajaxSuccess and ajaxComplete, but doesn't work either.